# Modelling relationship for a table containing two foreign keys

Tags: laravel, relationship

I have the following SQL tables for example:

```
    guards
    guard_id guard_name guard_type

    roles
    role_id role_name security_priviledge

    guard_roles
    gr_id guard_id role_id
```

How would I define this relationship in Laravel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define two Models, App/Guard.php and App/Role.php and define their Many to Many relationship. For example:

On App/Guard.php:

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Guard extends Model
{
    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
    }
}
```

On App/Role.php:

```
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Role extends Model
{
    public function guard()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Guard');
    }
}
```